# Using Jsch ChannelSftp put to a GDG file on mainframe

Tags: sftp, jsch, mainframe, zos

I'm currently stuck on trying to find a way to put to a generation data group (GDG) on mainframe(zos) using Jsch.

The command line syntax would be

```
put myFile.txt GDG.MYGDG(+1)
```

This I know works fine when using sftp or ftp command via a linux shell.  I have not found any way to replicate this via the put method of the ChannelSftp class.

I have searched wide and far looking for examples and not found any which makes me think it is not possible with this framework.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

adding some example code.  This is not the full code but shows what I have tried.

```
String localFileName = localFile.getName();
String remoteFile = "GDG.GDGROUP1(+1)";
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);


  ChannelSftp channelSftp = this.getChannelSftp();
  String pwd = channelSftp.pwd();
  channelSftp.put(inputStream, remoteFile);
```

The put call always returns that this is directory.  I have also tried this for the remote file:

```
String remoteFile = localFile + " GDG.GDGROUP1(+1)";
```

This just returns failure.

I have tried absolute path using // and /-/.  So far nothing has worked.

Comment: The ChannelSftp class has several methods for putting a file onto the remote server. Just what trouble are you having? Are you having trouble getting one of them to work? Do you have any source code that you could add to your question to illustrate the trouble you're having?

Comment: Added some code.  Not the entire thing but should show what I have tried.

Comment: If your server is the Dovetailed Technologies sftp server, have you tried setting the `gdgnt` option prior to your `put`?

Comment: I tried setting gdgnt before the put and got the same results.  It would seem i either don't know the right syntax when using Jsch or it simply doesn't support it.